# change help center URL links from http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com to https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, hyperlinks

I just got a "not secure" warning from my Chrome browser when clicking a link to this meta site in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic because it was using http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead of https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com. Could this be updated please?

Related: [2 links on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2983/81885)

Comment: Not sure which links you refer to; all I can see there properly point to `softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com`. So can you tell which link it was?

Comment: @Izzy all three in `/help/on-topic`: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information, http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software, http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, but for me those links show `softwarerecs.meta.*`. OK, invoked the editor to take a closer look: indeed there it's the way you say. And what's more: `http://`, not `https://`. Must be one of my scripts auto-adjusting that when the page is rendered /o\

So thanks for reporting, should be fixed now!

Comment: thanks, Izzy! Looks like [that's actually the only editable help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/997587) (I thought there might have been more).

Comment: Seems like, yes. I remember a few years back we looked for what we could adjust ourselves, and it wasn't as much as we hoped for. So this is the best I could do for now. Hopefully there are no broken pieces in other parts, as those would need to be addressed at SE staff. // Thanks for the link btw, that was missing in my collection! Bookmarked right away :)